# Classic ASP Date issue while moving from IIS 8.0 to 8.5

Tags: date, asp-classic

I'm stuck with an issue on an old classic asp project.

I'm trying to migrate to another server which has same OS(Windows 2012) and MS-SQL 2012 but ADO versions are different. Current server(S1) has ADO 6.2 & IIS 8.0.9200 whereas the new server(S2) has ADO 6.3 and IIS 8.5.9600

Now my issue is on S1, date is displayed as '8/1/2017 7:22:05 PM' but on S2 it gives '01-08-2017 19:22:49'

This gives error while working with TSQL on S2

> Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 error '80040e07'
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: I have supported classic asp applications on windows server for three years. i faced such problems and the solution was always to adjust the time format / time zone on the server. If irt didn't work, then you need to check your T-SQL to catch the correct format. Which time zone do you have?

Comment: I've set time zone UTC + 5:30 and formats are as follows
Short format: M/d/yyyy
Short time: h:mm tt
Long format: dddd, MMMM d, yyyy
Long Time: h:mm:ss tt